# How to format a custom type in the json result?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a custom class, which basically boils down to this:

```
public class MyValue
{
    public MyValue(int v)
    {
        Value = v;
    }

    public int Value {get;}
}
```

I use this class as a property on various classes. When my API returns a class (which has a `MyValue` property), the json returned looks like:

```
"propertyOfTypeMyValue": {
    "value": 4
}
```

I don't want this. What I'd like is that the json returned looks like this:

```
"propertyOfTypeMyValue": 4
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You would use a custom Converter: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get the output you want by creating a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for your `MyValue` class like this:

```
public class MyValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyValue);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) 
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer) 
            return new MyValue(Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value));
        throw new JsonException("Unexpected token type: " + reader.TokenType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((MyValue)value).Value);
    }
}
```

To use the converter, mark the `MyValue` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyValueConverter))]
public class MyValue
{
    public MyValue(int v)
    {
        Value = v;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A4eU87